# Sql Sequelize - Need Random Data with pagination

Tags: sql, node.js, database, random, sequelize.js

I need random data from database with pagination.

Example data in our database: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

I need limit = 3, current page = 1, with random data from database.
like in first page data like this [ 2,5,1 ] then second page data never be duplicate.

is there any solution for this?

I used this for random data but it does not work in pagination.
Sequelize.fn( 'RAND' )

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Below action method you can implement to have pagination

```
   async read(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            logging.info(NAMESPACE, 'enter read()', req.body);
            const limit = req.query?.limit as number | undefined;
            let page = req.query?.page as number | undefined;
    
            if (!page)
                page = 0;
            let offset = 0;
    
            if (limit)
                offset = 0 + (page - 1) * limit;
            const records = await TodoInstance.findAll({ where: {}, limit: limit, offset: offset });
            return res.json({
                records,
                msg: 'Fetched todos',
                status: 200
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            logging.error(NAMESPACE, 'Error while reading todo', error);
            return res.json({
                msg: 'fail to read todo',
                status: 500,
                route: '/read'
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can use the following approach:

```sql
SELECT setseed(0.5);
SELECT *, random() as ord FROM temp ORDER BY ord OFFSET 0 LIMIT 3;
SELECT setseed(0.5);
SELECT *, random() as ord FROM temp ORDER BY ord OFFSET 3 LIMIT 3;
SELECT setseed(0.5);
SELECT *, random() as ord FROM temp ORDER BY ord OFFSET 6 LIMIT 3;
```

[SQL Playground](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f38fa/24)

Also Ive found the following in Sequalize docs:

```js
Subtask.findAll({
  // Will order randomly based on the dialect (instead of fn('RAND') or fn('RANDOM'))
  order: sequelize.random(),
  offset: 0,
  limit: 3
});
```

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html